# In terminal It shows GIT branch with slash question mark

Tags: git, git-branch

I just started a brand new repo. Nothing is in it except for a ReadMe file. When I added a folder to my repo and put a test.html file in the folder, in terminal the branch shows up like this:

```
(master/?) akaminsky:~/code/penguin $
```

If I delete the file I put in the folder, it goes back to normal

```
(master) akaminsky:~/code/penguin $
```

Any ideas?

update: 
when I try to do git add . and I recreated the test.html file, terminal looks like this:

(master/A) akaminsky:~/code/penguin $

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing the `?` indicates that the working copy is dirty -- either you added, deleted, or modified a file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming it's letting you know the current status of your working copy - the `?` means it's dirty, the `A` means you've staged some files but have yet to commit.